# Margin-bottom does not create space below an <a> tag

Tags: css, margin

Within my HTML form, I have a link `<a href='...'>...</a>` followed by a label `<label ...>...</label>`. I set a bottom margin for the link like this:

```
form a {
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```

When I inspect elements using Google Chrome Console, the `a` tag indeed has a `margin-bottom` of 10px. But the label is directly below it with no space. How can I generate some space there?

Comment: `a href` tags are not containers and thus cannot have a margin applied to them.  Put the link inside a container (div, span, table, etc) and apply a margin to that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It'd be better practice to wrap the link in a paragraph `<p>` tag. Then add the margin to that.

```
<p><a href="#">...</a></p>
```

And the css:

```
p {
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```

The element needs to be block level to achieve the vertical spacing. Alternatively, you could force block on the `a` with `display: block`

Answer (score 9):

By default `a` tags are inline elements and therefore can't have margins added. You would need to make your `a` tag display like a block element to see margins and other attributes associated with block elements:

```
form a {
    display: block;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```

Comment: +1, `display: inline-block` may be enough, depending on what the OP wants to achieve.

Comment: To be pedantic, you're wrong: You can't actually make `a` a *block* element (or a "black" element, which is what you've written). You can, however, make it *display* like a block element. (Or, as Linus says, an inline-block element. (Also, your comma splice is bugging me.)

Comment: Your info is very revealing. I didn't know that "<a> tags are inline elements"! I tried it many ways, and it just didn't work! Then I added "display: block;", and boom! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Make the anchor tag `display:inline-block;` so that it takes margin.

```
form a {
    display:inline-block;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```